# Drag and Drop item from one div to another div and clone item using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, jsplumb

I have created 2 divs and I want to drag an item from one of the div and drop it in the other div and it must clone. How do I implement draggable() and droppable() function in vuejs. I am very new to vuejs. thanks in advance

Comment: Your `draggable` and `droppable` are methods in your Vue component.

Comment: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Comment: https://github.com/tao12345666333/vue-jsPlumb/blob/master/src/views/Index.vue You can see this. maybe helpful.